# How to correctly call a function name from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement

I'm writing an ATM program to practice OO design, and I'm creating a text-based interface to prototype a GUI.  As part of my program I have a `main_menu` function which offers various options on an account once they have validated their information.  I was reading up on switch/case statements, and their apparent absence in Python, and then found some formulas on the official site https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python about how to create a similar effect.  Here is the example:

```
def function_1(...):
    ...

functions = {'a': function_1,
             'b': function_2,
             'c': self.method_1, ...}

func = functions[value]
func()
```

I think I'm close, but I'm getting the error that a string is not callable.  The functions in my dictionary all map to corresponding functions in my ATM class.

```
class ATMTextInterface(object):

    def __init__(self, atm):
        self.atm = atm
        self.name = ''
        self.user_id = ''
        self.pin = ''
        self._run()

    def _get_inputs(self):
        self.name = input('Please enter your name: ')
        self.user_id = eval(input('Please enter your User ID: '))
        self.pin = eval(input("Now enter your pin: "))
        return self.name, self.user_id, self.pin

    def _initial_screen(self):
        user_in = ''
        while user_in != 'Q':
            print('{:^10}'.format('Welcome to the ATM!\n'))
            print('(A)ccess Account')
            print('(Q)uit')
            user_in = input('Please enter selection: ').upper()

            if user_in == 'A':
                user_info = self._get_inputs()
                if self.atm.access_account(user_info[1], user_info[2]):
                    print('Information successfully validated.')
                    break
                else:
                    add_new = input('Information not recognized.  '
                                    'Would you like to add a new user? ')
                    if add_new == 'Y':
                        self.atm.add_user(*user_info)
            elif user_in == 'Q':
                continue
            else:
                print('Selection not recognized, please try again.')

    def _main_menu(self):
        user_in = ''
        functions = {
            '1': 'check_balance',
            '2': 'make_deposit',
            '3': 'make_withdrawal',
            '4': 'select_account',
            '5': 'transfer_money'
        }
        while user_in != 'Q':
            print('{}{}{}\n'.format('-' * 10, 'MAIN MENU', '-' * 10))
            print('Please select one of the following options: \n\n')
            options = ['1. Check Balance', '2. Make Deposit',
                       '3. Make Withdrawal', '4. Select Account',
                       '5. Transfer Funds', '(Q)uit']
            print('\n'.join(options))
            user_in = input('>> ') #.upper()
            func = 'self.atm.' + functions.get(user_in)
            func()

    def _run(self):
        self._initial_screen()
        self._main_menu()
```

Comment: Look at the example's `functions` dict, and look at yours. Do you see any differences in the syntax between your dict and the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
functions = {
        '1': 'check_balance',
        '2': 'make_deposit',
        '3': 'make_withdrawal',
        '4': 'select_account',
        '5': 'transfer_money'
    }
```

by

```
functions = {
            '1': check_balance,
            '2': make_deposit,
            '3': make_withdrawal,
            '4': select_account,
            '5': transfer_money
        }
```

And moreover, all the values in the dict like check_balance must be a module level function defined with in your file.

Comment: I modified them to be self.atm.* items.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You may try `getattr(obj, attr)`. In your code, transfer

```
func = 'self.atm.' + functions.get(user_in)
```

to

```
func = getattr(self.atm, functions.get(user_in))
```